# web scraping with beautifulsoup using python, saving to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to the programming, currently I am learning to do web scraping using python. Your answer or suggestion will be beneficial to my learning process.

**Here is the part of HTML. I want to extract information including data, name and its usage.**

```
<h2>Jan. 2020</h2>
<p><strong>nameA:</strong>&nbsp;usage for somethingA</p>
<p><strong>nameB:</strong>&nbsp;usage for somethingB</p>

<h2>Dec. 2019</h2>
<p><strong>nameC:</strong>&nbsp;usage for somethingC</p>
<p><strong>nameD:</strong>&nbsp;usage for somethingD</p>
<p><strong>nameE:</strong>&nbsp;usage for somethingE</p>
```

**Here is my scraping code.**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
res=requests.get("https://website for my web scraping")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

start = soup.find('h2', string = "Jan. 2020")
print (start.text)
for elem in start.next_siblings:
     if elem.name == 'h2':
         break
     if elem.name != 'p':
         continue
     print(elem.text)
     
start = soup.find('h2', string = "Dec. 2019")
print (start.text)
for elem in start.next_siblings:
     if elem.name == 'h2':
         break
     if elem.name != 'p':
         continue
     print(elem.text)
```

**The code worked and here is the output.**

```
Jan. 2020
nameA: usage for somethingA
nameB: usage for somethingB
Dec. 2019
nameC: usage for somethingC
nameD: usage for somethingD
nameE: usage for somethingE
```

But my main goal is to generate a table below including date, name and usage and saving the data to MySQL. How do I accomplish this?

```
Date        Name    Usage
Jan. 2020   nameA   somethingA
Jan. 2020   nameB   somethingB
Dec. 2019   nameC   somethingC
Dec. 2019   nameD   somethingD
Dec. 2019   nameE   somethingE
```

This website gets updated once a while and will have a new set of data (say March. 2020) added and an old set of data (say Nov. 2019) taken out.  How do I adjust the python code to reflect website change?

Comment: Please be more specific. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides or tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic].